# Tomcat bad_certificate

Tags: tomcat, ssl, certificate, client-certificates

I have a Tomcat Web Application. I can access this application via Browser (just for Authentication Test) and iOS App. Access from Browser is successfully but access from iOS fails. 
I'm using Client Certificates that are issued by Test Systems CA01.

I've tried to debug this and got this from stdout.log.
Comparing the output to a successfully authentication from browser i can see a user certificate after the ServerHelloDone.
In the output below i only see a bad certificate. Does this mean that no client certificate is send at all?

```
2015-12-04 15:42:47 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
trustStore is: D:\sapjvm\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=VeriSign Class 4 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=VeriSign Class 4 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xeca0a78b6e756a01cfc47ccc2f945ed7
  Valid from Fri Oct 01 02:00:00 CEST 1999 until Thu Jul 17 01:59:59 CEST 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Sep 01 02:00:00 CEST 2009 until Fri Jan 01 00:59:59 CET 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Test Systems CA01, DC=service, DC=local
  Issuer:  CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1c00000003c9b36a2e404adf5e000000000003
  Valid from Fri Aug 30 17:41:16 CEST 2013 until Wed Aug 30 17:51:16 CEST 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1a5
  Valid from Thu Aug 13 02:29:00 CEST 1998 until Tue Aug 14 01:59:00 CEST 2018

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Issuer:  CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x5d0b8ff4f7e571bb42ebeb95394709c4
  Valid from Fri Aug 09 11:11:02 CEST 2013 until Sun Aug 09 11:21:01 CEST 2043

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom

trustStore is: D:\sapjvm\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=VeriSign Class 4 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=VeriSign Class 4 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xeca0a78b6e756a01cfc47ccc2f945ed7
  Valid from Fri Oct 01 02:00:00 CEST 1999 until Thu Jul 17 01:59:59 CEST 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Test Systems CA01, DC=service, DC=local
  Issuer:  CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1c00000003c9b36a2e404adf5e000000000003
  Valid from Fri Aug 30 17:41:16 CEST 2013 until Wed Aug 30 17:51:16 CEST 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Issuer:  CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x5d0b8ff4f7e571bb42ebeb95394709c4
  Valid from Fri Aug 09 11:11:02 CEST 2013 until Sun Aug 09 11:21:01 CEST 2043

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
matching alias: tomcat
main, called closeSocket()
trustStore is: D:\sapjvm\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=VeriSign Class 4 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=VeriSign Class 4 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xeca0a78b6e756a01cfc47ccc2f945ed7
  Valid from Fri Oct 01 02:00:00 CEST 1999 until Thu Jul 17 01:59:59 CEST 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Test Systems CA01, DC=service, DC=local
  Issuer:  CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1c00000003c9b36a2e404adf5e000000000003
  Valid from Fri Aug 30 17:41:16 CEST 2013 until Wed Aug 30 17:51:16 CEST 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Issuer:  CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x5d0b8ff4f7e571bb42ebeb95394709c4
  Valid from Fri Aug 09 11:11:02 CEST 2013 until Sun Aug 09 11:21:01 CEST 2043

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
***
found key for : sap-got.Test-systems.de (Test systems ca01)
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=sap-got.Test-systems.de
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 22123926758697009262258111061486336884610288264863787625812112845880702736101273917016534437447665766846125008617866643955551947101411148413012604219187330006254424722008021180407169654029631760797839672800683653783080962243139427869971539215873206960626172133758187453406840671208017399584676497257669933088839937894969227220519632661364303428824625937652934701909375679107963751486819578490567836639073500732143796070923627980427070479074266152166879295422638389139282005428679551047181832021715313558454638651723035991938100998118073431659189369246608941602316712205339080408975996032167437643207582045090112543619
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Mon Oct 20 13:13:09 CEST 2014,
               To: Sun Oct 18 13:13:09 CEST 2020]
  Issuer: CN=Test Systems CA01, DC=service, DC=local
  SerialNumber: [    18000042 f32736f9 1f248f0f 55000100 0042f3]

Certificate Extensions: 8
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 0E 30 0C 30 0A 06 08   2B 06 01 05 05 07 03 01  ..0.0...+.......


[2]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 30 30 2E 06 26 2B 06   01 04 01 82 37 15 08 86  .00..&+.....7...
0010: F2 91 02 D9 A0 4C 83 E5   9D 25 82 F1 B9 41 83 FA  .....L...%...A..
0020: C1 0F 81 11 82 C3 82 56   82 DB D5 3E 02 01 64 02  .......V...>..d.
0030: 01 0C                                              ..


[3]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2
   accessLocation: URIName: http://crl.Test-systems.de/TestSystemsCA01.crt, 
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.Test-systems.de/ocsp]
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: CC 0B B7 19 27 9A 13 ED   CC C3 65 D9 F1 52 5F D5  ....'.....e..R_.
0010: 2F D7 E8 A7                                        /...
]

]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.Test-systems.de/TestSystemsCA01.crl]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 5E 8E 3F 24 CA B5 11 FA   A6 F7 98 62 4C DC B3 B2  ^.?$.......bL...
0010: 10 20 10 63                                        . .c
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: CD D3 96 B3 DE 65 CF 5F   E4 15 C7 93 46 66 E6 25  .....e._....Ff.%
0010: E9 A3 9B 77 D2 17 DE 8C   11 87 81 04 BB 8C D3 DD  ...w............
0020: 17 E3 F9 76 6B 5C 7F 5D   8F EE E5 30 3E BE 4D B9  ...vk\.]...0>.M.
0030: AB 43 EC DA 49 61 ED E8   FD 33 14 29 D7 27 35 81  .C..Ia...3.).'5.
0040: 84 F9 EC 1B 35 86 11 43   93 BA 26 E4 66 D8 C3 A0  ....5..C..&.f...
0050: 9F 15 62 57 CF 93 06 20   9C 30 56 C3 64 15 1B B2  ..bW... .0V.d...
0060: 96 E8 99 48 AB 0E 34 FC   F6 EF 26 2F 93 EB C9 C6  ...H..4...&/....
0070: 7A 5F 6B 11 89 5E A2 6F   FC 83 9F D8 7D 39 D5 99  z_k..^.o.....9..
0080: DA C9 A3 8F E8 D1 B3 61   97 49 0E 1E 0B 9C 50 B9  .......a.I....P.
0090: 61 D4 81 CD 2F CD 0E 3D   E9 0F 84 3F 3C 57 54 93  a.../..=...?<WT.
00A0: CE C3 8F 82 2E 6C B0 D0   91 AB 3E 36 C8 72 36 45  .....l....>6.r6E
00B0: 32 C8 13 32 90 B7 71 F7   BA 8F 0B 86 C5 DC 51 65  2..2..q.......Qe
00C0: 39 6B F7 BB 5E 1B 04 3F   3B 87 95 AC D6 44 B4 CD  9k..^..?;....D..
00D0: 91 37 CC 2F 8A 51 C2 03   24 95 6E 5E E3 3A F8 92  .7./.Q..$.n^.:..
00E0: 22 8C BA AC D0 CD 36 CE   62 51 08 A6 18 EC 22 E1  ".....6.bQ....".
00F0: CD 84 C3 FD 86 F2 B3 47   A5 94 F3 96 84 69 42 CA  .......G.....iB.

]
***
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Issuer:  CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x5d0b8ff4f7e571bb42ebeb95394709c4
  Valid from Fri Aug 09 11:11:02 CEST 2013 until Sun Aug 09 11:21:01 CEST 2043

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Test Systems CA01, DC=service, DC=local
  Issuer:  CN=Test Systems RootCA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1c00000003c9b36a2e404adf5e000000000003
  Valid from Fri Aug 30 17:41:16 CEST 2013 until Wed Aug 30 17:51:16 CEST 2028

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
matching alias: sap-got.Test-systems.de (Test systems ca01)
main, called closeSocket()
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
com.businessobjects.webpath.rebean3ws.Activator
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
http-bio-8443-Acceptor-0, called closeSocket()
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
http-bio-443-Acceptor-0, called closeSocket()
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
http-bio-443-Acceptor-0, setSoTimeout(60000) called
http-bio-443-exec-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 212
*** ClientHello, Unknown-3.3
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1449174438 bytes = { 74, 244, 128, 133, 192, 167, 255, 143, 170, 131, 121, 214, 27, 55, 115, 19, 31, 210, 124, 219, 190, 88, 207, 68, 252, 32, 251, 207 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, Unknown 0xc0:0x2c, Unknown 0xc0:0x2b, Unknown 0xc0:0x24, Unknown 0xc0:0x23, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0xc0:0x30, Unknown 0xc0:0x2f, Unknown 0xc0:0x28, Unknown 0xc0:0x27, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x9d, Unknown 0x0:0x9c, Unknown 0x0:0x3d, Unknown 0x0:0x3c, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Unsupported extension server_name, [host_name: sap-got.Test-systems.de]
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension signature_algorithms, data: 00:0c:05:01:04:01:02:01:05:03:04:03:02:03
Unsupported extension type_13172, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:19:08:73:70:64:79:2f:33:2e:31:06:73:70:64:79:2f:33:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
***
%% Created:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1449174486 bytes = { 248, 125, 12, 32, 11, 129, 137, 149, 25, 211, 219, 120, 146, 15, 17, 95, 238, 212, 86, 186, 90, 46, 20, 14, 92, 221, 162, 85 }
Session ID:  {86, 97, 166, 214, 248, 0, 49, 223, 215, 193, 133, 184, 33, 159, 31, 30, 166, 227, 93, 71, 247, 107, 31, 17, 37, 173, 50, 63, 50, 135, 107, 208}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=sap-got.Test-systems.de
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 22123926758697009262258111061486336884610288264863787625812112845880702736101273917016534437447665766846125008617866643955551947101411148413012604219187330006254424722008021180407169654029631760797839672800683653783080962243139427869971539215873206960626172133758187453406840671208017399584676497257669933088839937894969227220519632661364303428824625937652934701909375679107963751486819578490567836639073500732143796070923627980427070479074266152166879295422638389139282005428679551047181832021715313558454638651723035991938100998118073431659189369246608941602316712205339080408975996032167437643207582045090112543619
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Mon Oct 20 13:13:09 CEST 2014,
               To: Sun Oct 18 13:13:09 CEST 2020]
  Issuer: CN=Test Systems CA01, DC=service, DC=local
  SerialNumber: [    18000042 f32736f9 1f248f0f 55000100 0042f3]

Certificate Extensions: 8
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 0E 30 0C 30 0A 06 08   2B 06 01 05 05 07 03 01  ..0.0...+.......


[2]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 30 30 2E 06 26 2B 06   01 04 01 82 37 15 08 86  .00..&+.....7...
0010: F2 91 02 D9 A0 4C 83 E5   9D 25 82 F1 B9 41 83 FA  .....L...%...A..
0020: C1 0F 81 11 82 C3 82 56   82 DB D5 3E 02 01 64 02  .......V...>..d.
0030: 01 0C                                              ..


[3]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2
   accessLocation: URIName: http://crl.Test-systems.de/TestSystemsCA01.crt, 
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.Test-systems.de/ocsp]
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: CC 0B B7 19 27 9A 13 ED   CC C3 65 D9 F1 52 5F D5  ....'.....e..R_.
0010: 2F D7 E8 A7                                        /...
]

]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.Test-systems.de/TestSystemsCA01.crl]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 5E 8E 3F 24 CA B5 11 FA   A6 F7 98 62 4C DC B3 B2  ^.?$.......bL...
0010: 10 20 10 63                                        . .c
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: CD D3 96 B3 DE 65 CF 5F   E4 15 C7 93 46 66 E6 25  .....e._....Ff.%
0010: E9 A3 9B 77 D2 17 DE 8C   11 87 81 04 BB 8C D3 DD  ...w............
0020: 17 E3 F9 76 6B 5C 7F 5D   8F EE E5 30 3E BE 4D B9  ...vk\.]...0>.M.
0030: AB 43 EC DA 49 61 ED E8   FD 33 14 29 D7 27 35 81  .C..Ia...3.).'5.
0040: 84 F9 EC 1B 35 86 11 43   93 BA 26 E4 66 D8 C3 A0  ....5..C..&.f...
0050: 9F 15 62 57 CF 93 06 20   9C 30 56 C3 64 15 1B B2  ..bW... .0V.d...
0060: 96 E8 99 48 AB 0E 34 FC   F6 EF 26 2F 93 EB C9 C6  ...H..4...&/....
0070: 7A 5F 6B 11 89 5E A2 6F   FC 83 9F D8 7D 39 D5 99  z_k..^.o.....9..
0080: DA C9 A3 8F E8 D1 B3 61   97 49 0E 1E 0B 9C 50 B9  .......a.I....P.
0090: 61 D4 81 CD 2F CD 0E 3D   E9 0F 84 3F 3C 57 54 93  a.../..=...?<WT.
00A0: CE C3 8F 82 2E 6C B0 D0   91 AB 3E 36 C8 72 36 45  .....l....>6.r6E
00B0: 32 C8 13 32 90 B7 71 F7   BA 8F 0B 86 C5 DC 51 65  2..2..q.......Qe
00C0: 39 6B F7 BB 5E 1B 04 3F   3B 87 95 AC D6 44 B4 CD  9k..^..?;....D..
00D0: 91 37 CC 2F 8A 51 C2 03   24 95 6E 5E E3 3A F8 92  .7./.Q..$.n^.:..
00E0: 22 8C BA AC D0 CD 36 CE   62 51 08 A6 18 EC 22 E1  ".....6.bQ....".
00F0: CD 84 C3 FD 86 F2 B3 47   A5 94 F3 96 84 69 42 CA  .......G.....iB.

]
***
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS
Cert Authorities:
<CN=Test Systems RootCA>
<CN=Test Systems CA01, DC=service, DC=local>
*** ServerHelloDone
http-bio-443-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1372
http-bio-443-exec-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 7
*** Certificate chain
***
http-bio-443-exec-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = bad_certificate
http-bio-443-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-bio-443-exec-1, called closeSocket()
http-bio-443-exec-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
http-bio-443-exec-1, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
http-bio-443-exec-1, called close()
http-bio-443-exec-1, called closeInternal(true)
```